# Why do second order linear ODE have solutions $y_1$ and $y_2=v y_1$ where $v$ is a function of x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y^{\prime \prime}+P(x) y^{\prime}+Q(x) y=0$$
Provided we know a solution $y_1$ we assume the second linearly independent solution to be $y_2=v y_1$ substitute this back into the ODE and end up with this relation $y_2=y_1 \int \frac{1}{y_1^2} e^{-\int P(x) d x} d x$

My issue with this is that why is it necessary that the solution be $y_2=v y_1$, is it never possible that the second solution cannot be expressed as a product of the first solution and a function of x? I am struggling to understand why the first and second solutions have such a relation between them.

Comment: Why not? The quotient $v=y_2/y_1$ exists everywhere but at the roots of $y_1$, and is as smooth as the solutions where it exists. And as the roots are isolated, the quotient and its differential equation are interesting enough.

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar. I had the proof with me but didn't quite get the choice of $y_2 = vy_1$. I think Lutz Lehmann's and ultralegend5385 explanation pretty much does it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I may not be the best equipped for this question fully, but my intuition states that no matter what $y_1$ is, $y_1$ is still a function of $x$ and so is $y_2$ so if we just define some $v$ to be the difference in multiplicative factors (the quotient as the comment said) then it’s obvious that $v$ must be a function of x, because both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are.  Similarly if we have the opposite question, such that $v$ and $y_1$ are functions of $x$ such that $y_2 = vy_1$ then again, it is clear that $y_2$ itself is a function of $x$ because it is a product of functions which depend solely on $x$.  Hope this helps intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

Note whatever $y_2(x)$ is, it is a function of $x$, and $y_1(x)$ is a function of $x$ too (nonzero everywhere). The assumption $y_1\neq 0$ is required for the mentioned formula to work as you divide by $y_1$. Thus, the ratio $y_2(x)/y_1(x)$ is a also a function. Call that $v(x)$. Then, $y_2(x)=v(x)y_1(x)$ is also a solution. So, you can substitute $vy_1$ for $y$ and try to find $v$ (which is just the formula you mentioned).

Hope this helps. :)